# why @InjectMocks with a Spring bean and not use the combo @Resource+@MockBean

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

sometimes, we have this kind of configuration, as class depedency :

```
@Service    
public class StudentService {

private PenService pen;

public StudentService(PenService pen) {
    this.pen = pen;
}
```

}

and Test class configured as :

```
public class test {

@InjectMocks
StudentService student;

@Mock
PenService pen;

@Test
public void someTest() {
    // some code
}
```

}

question is :
why NOT use this kind of configuration, with Spring annotations ?

```
public class test {

    @Resource
    StudentService student;

    @MockBean
    PenService pen;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        // some code
    }

}
```

it seems to be more logical ?
In a Spring initialization context, what is the difference between :
[@InjectMocks+@Mocks] combo and [@Resource+@MockBean] combo ?

Comment: 1 uses plain mockito and odesn't require a spring context, the second requires a spring context and spring to be in control. The first is faster then he second.

Comment: ok, i know that, but why in some exemples on the net, we find some [@InjectMocks+@Mocks] usage when the parent class to be tested is a Spring managed class ?

Comment: The fact that something uses Spring doesn't mean you need to use it for testing if you want to test only the service. That would be overkill and slow down your tests.

Comment: it's absolutly clear.